# Strange behavior of PowerShell code - returns wrong result unless session is restarted

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

I have this code  which check for the existence of a project in SSISDB. On the first run I make sure the project is there and it returns the correct value. But then I delete the project and run the code again but it then returns 1 again. When I restart the session then it starts to return the correct answer again. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
import-module sqlserver;
$TargetInstanceName = "localhost\default"
$TargetFolderName = "FolderForTesting";
$ProjectName = "ProjectTesting";

$catalog = Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SSIS\$TargetInstanceName\Catalogs\SSISDB\
$folder = $catalog.Folders["$TargetFolderName"];
$project = $folder.Projects["$ProjectName"];

       if($null -eq $project){
            Return 0

        } else {
            Return 1            
        }
```

Comment: Try to insert `$catalog.Refresh()` after the `Get-Item` line. From https://sqlvariant.com/2017/01/refreshing-the-sql-server-powershell-provider/

Comment: @zett42: No it still does not give correct answer.

Comment: @zett42: thanks, if the project is not there and I call refresh on it, i.e. `$Project.Refresh()`, then I get an error. Can you please paste a link for `ForEach('Dispose')`? Because I am working on a production machine and don't want to drop something...

Comment: Then, can't you use `$Project.Refresh()` inside a `try{..} catch{..}` and if you enter the catch block, you know the project isn't found and you can safely return 0

Comment: I've removed the `Dispose` suggestion, it was too much of a guesswork. The `Refresh()` method seems like a sound solution though, so I've turned it into an answer. If you get it working with less `Refresh()` calls, please let me know so I can update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining mine and [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s helpful comments into a possible solution:

```sh
import-module sqlserver;
$TargetInstanceName = "localhost\default"
$TargetFolderName = "FolderForTesting";
$ProjectName = "ProjectTesting";

try {
    $catalog = Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SSIS\$TargetInstanceName\Catalogs\SSISDB\  
    $folder = $catalog.Folders[ $TargetFolderName ]
    $project = $folder.Projects[ $ProjectName ]

    if($null -eq $project){
        Return 0
    } else {
        $project.Refresh()  # Causes an exception if project actually doesn't exist
        Return 1            
    }
}
catch {
    return 0
}
```

This is based on [Refreshing the SQL Server PowerShell Provider](https://sqlvariant.com/2017/01/refreshing-the-sql-server-powershell-provider/) and [PS + SQLPS refreshing the SQL Server object](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/47pe4a/ps_sqlps_refreshing_the_sql_server_object/) and your own testing. I couldn't find any official information regarding the topic.

Comment: My working solution currently only calls refresh() on `$project` using `try/catch` as Theo wrote in the comment. So the other calls to refresh are not needed. . And I only use `try/catch` when I call it for `$project` and the rest of the code is outside the `try/catch`.

Comment: This is how my solution looks now: `$project = $folder.Projects["$ProjectName"];
try {
    $project.Refresh();
    $hi = 1
}
catch {

 $hi = 0; 
}

return $hi`. The code before this is the same as the question.

Comment: @xhr489 Thanks for the confirmation. Though in case `$project` is `$null`, it doesn't make sense to call `Refresh` on it, so I've moved it into the `else` branch.

Comment: Yes that is even better.